# Is it possible to atomically add several items to DynamoDB array with checking their occurance in it (to avoid duplication)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have email black list stored as one item in DynamoDB

```
// item example
{
  id: "blackList" // PrimaryKey of item
  list: [ "email_1@example.com", "email_2@example.com" ]
}
```

It is possible to add new email to the list and the same time check if it's not already presented in the list (to avoid duplication) by atomic update:

```
const email = "email_new@example.com";
const params = {
    TableName: "myTable",
    Key: {
        id: "blackList"
    },
    AttributeUpdates: {
        list: {
          Action: "ADD",
          Value: [email] // several emails can also be added with incorrect Expected check
        },
    },
    Expected: {
        list: {
            ComparisonOperator: "NOT_CONTAINS",
            Value: email
        },
    }
};

await docClient.update(params).promise();
```

The question is whether it's possible to perform the same atomic operation for several emails at once?

Comment: As I know first you need to get `List` of email by `id` then prepare `array` and then update.

Comment: @IftekharDani all of the are stored in the same item of DynamoDB in array having naturally only one id. And doing this operations using 2 or more calls to DB is super simple. I'm asking about one atomic call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a string set if you want there to be no duplicates. If you want to see if they existed in the set before you added them, return the old item.

```
const email = "email_new@example.com";
const params = {
    TableName: "myTable",
    Key: {
        id: "blackList"
    },
    UpdateExpression: "ADD #email :email",
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
      "#email": "email"
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ":email": docClient.createSet(email)
    }
};

await docClient.update(params).promise();
```

This will add the `email_new@example.com` to the email attribute as a string set. If the email attribute doesn't exist on the object it will be created.

See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.UpdateExpressions.html#Expressions.UpdateExpressions.ADD for the documentation.

Comment: Can you provide an example how to add several items to a set/map with update operation without deleting of existent ones? "ADD" operation is not supported for maps while "PUT" operation removes existent items.